# Number of $3$-subsets

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Find number of all $3$-subsets $s$ of set $S=\left\{2,3,\ldots,50,53,55\right\}$ so that:
> $\forall x,y\in s (x\ne y \rightarrow |x-y|>2)$.

I need to solve this using the theorem:
For $k, n, v ∈ N_0$, $n\ge (k − 1)v$, the number of
$k$-subsets $S ⊆ [n]$ so that $x, y ∈ S,(x\ne y), |x − y| > v$, is
$f_v (n, k)$ = $(n − (k − 1)v \choose k$.

I have a problem because here in set $S$ I don't have first $n$ natural numbers, so I'm not sure how to use this theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints :**

- Only one of $53$, $55$ can be chosen at a time.
- There is a bijection between desired subsets of ${1,2,\ldots,49}$ and ${2,3,\ldots,50}$. E.g., ${1,5,49}$ corresponds to ${2,6,50}$.

---

Comment: Well, then it would be easy, i could separate on three sets, one with numbers $\left\{1,2,\ldots ,49\right\}$, without $53$ and $55$, and the other two with $53$ and $55$. But what when it starts from 2?

Comment: There is really no difference whether the set is ${1,2,...49}$ or ${2,3,...50}$. Both have 49 consecutive elements, so desired number of subsets is same.

Comment: So i can write it like that? And when i look at the set with 53, i choose two elements beacuse i already have one, and the first number that satisfies the condition $|x-y|>2$ is 49, so for that set i have $f_2(49,2)$, right? And similar for the set that contains 55.

Comment: Yes, that is clear now. Just to clear what i wrote in last comment.

Comment: Yes that's right. In addition, there'll be $f_{2}(49,3)$ when neither ${53,55}$ chosen.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot.